# How to control the "Updating skeletons" background task in PyCharm for IronPython interpreter?

Tags: ironpython, pycharm, python

Is there a way to suppress, stop or, otherwise, control the settings for, or display of, background tasks in PyCharm? Selecting the IronPython interpreter causes it to update skeletons (seemingly) *every time* the interpreter is selected and usually takes 20-30 minutes to complete, rendering the IDE nearly unusable. Most times, I can't even carry on with normal work as most of the context menus are disabled during the operation.

Answer (score 2):

Because today 2013-11-14Thu, it's 2 years after your bug and no other people are complaining about the pycharm, now 3.0, problem, I believe it is actually probably a Mac OSX issue. Numerous programs on my brand new 10.8.5 machine run way way over 100%. Pycharm updating skeletons was just taking 330% and making my fan spin crazily.

From lots of previous googling I found a little script that can temporarily fix the problem; 
http://www.willnolan.com/cputhrottle/cputhrottle.html
Run it as so;

```
sudo CpuThrottle xxx 25
```

where xxx = your process ID per Activity Monitor, and 25 = whatever %cpu you wish to limit it to. Upon clicking return, it will only last as long as one does not click ctrl-c. I read on the mac boards about a bug in the code where it would seek to use all available resources in looking for system updates, the same as this thing is doing. So I guess, alas we have to live with it. At least we have the little tool. Sigh.

Comment: This was on Windows 7.

Comment: ok. I do not think I have seen the problem on Win8. I run both win/mac. I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: As for 2015-01-25, problem still appears. `Updating skeletons` has not been finished yet.

Comment: @George, which machine OS/version are you on?

Comment: @AnneTheAgile Windows 8.1 x64. This operation took about one hour. When I opened PyCharm again, it seems this operation was not performed again. I think it's how it should work normally. Anyway, it would be convenient to mark some packages as ignored.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue on Windows 8.1 x64. updating skeletons and indexing blocks pycharm. After that, the UI again hangs on opening top bar menus and i have to the kill PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

This was causing me problems because while this process is running, Jupyter-in-Intellij doesn't display the side panel where you can print things out. So it's pretty much a blocker.

I did several things which together resolved the problem:

- I updated Intellij via "Check for updates..." and updating everything that was presented
- I restarted Intellij after the update
- I deleted a large (20,000 lines) sample JSON file from my project following the [advice of this post on the Intellij forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205806059/comments/360000418759) that mentioned excluding or deleting files that weren't necessary to the project because the skeletons task would run on those

Unfortunately, I am not 100% certain what fixed it because I deleted the file as soon as my IDE came back up. Hopefully this answer will help someone in the future because Jupyter server within Intellij/PyCharm is excellent!

Answer (score -8):

Please upgrade to PyCharm 2.0. It's likely that the problem with generating skeletons of binary modules is already fixed.

Comment: year 2020. pycharm 2018.3; anaconda 2020.3; still updating skeletons and indexing libraries